# To Rsync files where permission denied

Tags: permissions, find, rsync

I want to find those files which I cannot copy to another location such that I could do Rsync. 
I have an external HDD and my system´s HDD. 
The external HDD has files which my system is missing. 
I am thinking how to do this.

I can find those files/directories with permission denied -messages by

```
find / ! -perm /u+r
```

where some permissions are

```
drwx------ 1  501 root       6 Oct 22  2014 PortableCV_WebCruiter_20141022
```

The following command may work from [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/rsync/cnN5bmM=/sort-by-votes), since remote data can be considered here as external HDD

```
rsync --rsync-path 'sudo rsync' username@source:/folder/ /local/
```

which

> Rsync remote data as root using sudo If your user has sudo on the
>   remote box, you can rsync data as root without needing to login as
>   root. This is very helpful if the remote box does not allow root to
>   login over SSH (which is a common security restriction).

How can you rsync files with permission denied problems between external HDD and system HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip the unreadable files:

```
find /external/hd/folder ! -readable -print >unreadable_files
rsync -a --exclude-from=unreadable_files /external/hd/folder/ /local/folder
```

This assumes that you're using GNU `find`, and that your filenames don't have embedded newlines.

If you want to copy all files, regardless of whether they are readable or not on the external disk:

```
sudo rsync -a /external/hd/folder/ /local/folder
sudo chown -R masi:masi /local/folder
```

This assumes you have enough privileges to run `sudo rsync` and `sudo chown`.

Comment: @Masi Well in the vast majority of cases files are unreadable because of ownership, not because of permissions.  There are uses for files that aren't readable by their owners, but those tend to be rare and pretty specialized.  I can't think of any reason for an usual _data_ file to be unreadable by its owner.

Comment: One experiment done with 0.5TB transfer from external HDD to my HDD 1TB Lenovo G30-50. The system Debian 8.1 fails to handle so much data such that the login is disturbed. There must be some lower level problems in the system. I opened a new thread about this experiment here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216628/16920

Comment: The problem with `rsync` is that it uses a lot of memory.  The more files you want to synch, the more memory it needs.  That's very likely the reason why your system crashed: `rsync` run out of memory, and OOM started committing "random acts of terrorism" (as [DJB](http://cr.yp.to/djb.html) likes to put it).  People that recommend using it to backup entire disks should keep this in mind.  You might still be able to copy the files with `cp -a`.  It's less efficient than `rsync`, but it also uses a lot less memory.  If that still doesn't work you could try copying subdirectories one at a time.

Comment: Any control system to control the memory?

Comment: The memory needed by `rsync`?  The only way AFAICT is to copy fewer files. _shrug_

Comment: @Icd047 How to well control it to maximize copying over time? This case is just a simplified situation. What is the exact link to this `http://cr.yp.to/djb.html "random acts of terrorism"`?

Comment: _How to well control it to maximize copying over time?_ - I don't have any silver bullet, sorry.  Copy fewer files at a time, or use a bigger machine. _What is the exact link to this `http://cr.yp.to/djb.html`_ - Just some guy famous for his opinionated rants, and for the quality of his software.  Not really relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you mount the external HDD to your system locally, then it's not remote. Unless I misunderstood and your HDD is running a rsync daemon and say, connecting over a network? But forget that, can you just mount the drive locally and as @mjturner says, all you need to do is make sure you run `rsync` as root and it's a direct copy `sudo rsync -a /mount/for/hdd/folder/ /local/` ??

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `rsync` to copy all of the files on the external HDD to the system HDD? It will not re-copy files that already exist.

Of course, be sure to do the copy as root to ensure that you copy all files and preserve permissions.